# How do you handle multiple value types in MySQL when inheritance isn't supported?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to create a table of attributes where each record is essentially just a name-value pair. The problem is that the value can be a string, integer or decimal and I'm using MySQL which doesn't support table inheritance. So, the question is - should I create a separate table for each value type or should I just create str_value, int_value and dec_value columns with an additional value_type column that tells you which type to use? There won't be many records in this table (less than 100), so performance shouldn't be much of an issue, but I just don't want to make a design decision that's going to make the SQL more complex than it has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having different tables, or even multiple columns where only one of the 3 are populated, is going to be a nightmare. Store it all as varchar along with a type column.

Answer (score 1):

When querying the database, you will always receive strings, no matter what the column type is - so there is no reason to make a design decision here - just store everything as a string.

By the way: Having an additional value_type column is redundant - the entry has the type of the only column that has a not-null value.

Comment: You said "the entry has the type of the only column that has a not-null value." How would you determine that in a SQL select statement?

Comment: It's ugly, but something like this should work:

SELECT IF(str_value IS NOT NULL,'str',IF(int_value IS NOT NULL,'int','dec')) AS type,IF(str_value IS NOT NULL,str_value,IF(int_value IS NOT NULL,int_value,dec_value)) FROM table

Comment: I would use an ugly case or if statement. Or I would query all columns at once and check in the application. Or would you rather query twice - once to check the type column and once more to retrieve the value?

Answer (score 0):

If you create different columns for each type, you're going to have to be smart about it in your code anyway...

Why not just store everything as a string and convert to the desired type in your code?